# React Native: Functional Component to Class Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-functional-component, react-native-gifted-chat, react-class-based-component

I am using [React Native Gifted Code](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat).

I am trying to convert the following example to class component:
[image: example image]

**And here's is my code snippet provided below:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        message: [{
            _id: 1,
            text: 'Hello developer',
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: 2,
                name: 'React Native',
                avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
            },
        }],
    }
}

componentDidMount() { }

onSend(messageSend = []) {
    this.setState(
        previousMessages => ({
            message: GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messageSend)
        })
    );
}

render() {
    const chat = <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.message}
        onSend={(messageSend) => this.onSend(messageSend)}
        user={{
            _id: 1,
        }}
    />;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                behaviour="padding"
                keyboardVerticalOffset={30}
                enabled
            >
                {chat}
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}
```

However, after converting to class component I am not the getting the desired outcome.
([something similar to this](https://snack.expo.io/@xcarpentier/giftedchat-playground))

> The issue is when sending a new message, it's 'replacing' the sender's
> message with my latest message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to add `previousMessages.messsage` instead of `previousMessages`.

**SOLUTION:**

```
//send message will no longer overlap/replace 'hello developer'
        onSend(messageSend = []) {
        this.setState(
            previousMessages => ({
                message: GiftedChat.append(previousMessages.messsage, messageSend)
            })
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code for class component based on your code

```
import React from 'react';
import {KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        message: [{
            _id: 1,
            text: 'Hello developer',
            createdAt: new Date(),
            user: {
                _id: 2,
                name: 'React Native',
                avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
            },
        }],
    }
  }

  //send message will no longer overlap/replace 'hello developer'
    onSend(messageSend = []) {
      this.setState(
        previousMessages => ({
            message: GiftedChat.append(previousMessages.messsage, messageSend)
        })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const chat = <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.message}
        onSend={(messageSend) => this.onSend(messageSend)}
        user={{
            _id: 1,
        }}
    />;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                behaviour="padding"
                keyboardVerticalOffset={30}
                enabled
            >
                {chat}
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    } else {
      return chat
    }
  }
}
```

You can also the check the sample in [expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29IOD.png)

**Output of the above code:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. However, I have managed to solve the issue. It seems there was a slight mistake I made on the `onSend` function, specifically `previousMessages` argument.